# How to remove duplicate values from an array of objects in react for select components of MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, duplicates, mern

I wanted to remove data from my array of objects. There are lots of duplicate values in my data, and this should be in the form of map so this is on my select value for selection.

**Array of Objects:**

```
rawData = [
0: {
  style_no: "BAG-011459",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Standard 21 x 36 Olive",
  mon: "21310026-4",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 51,
  force_update: 62,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 51,
  os: "Open",
},
1: {
  style_no: "BAG-010865",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Large 25 x 42  Olive",
  mon: "21310030-5",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 102,
  force_update: 63,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 102,
  os: "Open",
},
2: {
  style_no: "BAG-011932",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Large 25x42 Black",
  mon: "21310035-8",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 464,
  force_update: 64,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 464,
  os: "Open",
},
3:{
  style_no: "BAG-011932",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Large 25x42 Black",
  mon: "21310034-8",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 464,
  force_update: 65,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 464,
  os: "Open",
},
4:{
  style_no: "BAG-011931",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Standard 21x36 Black",
  mon: "21310034-7",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 160,
  force_update: 66,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 160,
  os: "Open",
},
5: {
  style_no: "BAG-011931",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Standard 21x36 Black",
  mon: "21310036-7",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 150,
  force_update: 67,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 150,
  os: "Open",
},
6: {
  style_no: "BAG-011931",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Standard 21x36 Black",
  mon: "21310035-7",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 160,
  force_update: 68,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 160,
  os: "Open",
},
7: {
  style_no: "BAG-011460",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Extra Large 30 x 50 Olive",
  mon: "21310034-6",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 456,
  force_update: 69,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 456,
  os: "Open",
},
8: {
  style_no: "BAG-011460",
  Item_description: "Hoplite Top Load Bag Extra Large 30 x 50 Olive",
  mon: "21310035-6",
  type: "Bags",
  oq: 456,
  force_update: 70,
  c_n: "WHITE DUCK",
  pl_q: 456,
  os: "Open",
},
]
```

**Select Body:**

```
    {/* Customer */}
    <FormControl sx={{ m: 0.5 }} variant="standard">
      <InputLabel
        style={{ fontSize: "15px" }}
        id="demo-customized-select-label"
      >
        Customer
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        required
        style={{
          fontSize: "12px",
          width: "125px",
        }}
        labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
        id="demo-customized-select"
        value={plandata.customer}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPlanData((prev) => ({ ...prev, customer: e.target.value }));
        }}
        input={<BootstrapInput />}
      >
        {rawData
          ?.filter((data) => data.type.includes(plandata.division))
          .map((value) => (
            <MenuItem value={value.c_n.toString()}>
              {value.c_n.toString()}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

**The snippet of the select box is**

[image: Select Button for cusomer]

Note: I already go through the answers which was related to this question but not find my query.
Edited: If any senior find me out for this problem is great, because yet I am unable to find solution.

Comment: There are quite a few ways to remove duplicate objects from an array. If you search stackoverflow you should be able to find several threads with good explanations. If youre looking for quick code: `const filteredArray = rawData.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(JSON.stringify(t) === JSON.stringify(v)))===i)` where `filteredArray` should be an array of unique objects

Comment: It make sense I'll try it and then comment on it that it is working or not.

Comment: @j-low sir there is nothing change, all the values are same as rawData,

Comment: The technique here is not to "find" an answer, it is to write one. Given an array of object where there might be duplicates, the correct approach is to write some JavaScript. To start, I would do a `console.log(data)` to see if that is the correct array to modify.

Comment: It looks like there is some use of `map()` and `filter()` and personally I find those a bit hard to understand. It's easier to do a for loop that iterates over `data` and build a new array. It's not wrong to use map/filter but that may be harder to understand.

Comment: I would suggest getting a new web page and hardwiring an array containing some of these objects. Or set up a link on JS Fiddle. You can then try that for loop over the array. For each entry, you only want to add it if a duplicate is not already there. Feel free to write some pseudocode first on paper, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
{/* Customer */}
<FormControl sx={{ m: 0.5 }} variant="standard">
  <InputLabel
    style={{ fontSize: "15px" }}
    id="demo-customized-select-label"
  >
    Customer
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    required
    style={{
      fontSize: "12px",
      width: "125px",
    }}
    labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
    id="demo-customized-select"
    value={plandata.customer}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setPlanData((prev) => ({ ...prev, customer: e.target.value }));
    }}
    input={<BootstrapInput />}
  >
    {rawData
      ?.filter((data) => data.type.includes(plandata.division))
      ?.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
      .map((value) => (
        <MenuItem value={value.c_n.toString()}>
          {value.c_n.toString()}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nope bro it seems to be no change in the values, all values are displayed, if you think you can modify it for this problem, then it is to be pleased to share the modify code.